# Core Data: How to model multiple one-to-many between two entities

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, relationship

I have two entities - **Item** and **Tag**. An Item can have one or more read-only (factory) tags that the user can't edit, and then one or more read-write (user) tags that the user can create at any time. I'm wondering how best to model this.

Of course I could just create **UserTag** and **FactoryTag** entities, but that would mean redundancy in maintaining two identical entities. I'd rather just have the single **Tag** entity.

If I use a single one-to-many relationship between **Item** and **Tag**, I'll have an NSSet that will contain both read-only and read-write tags. That's not ideal as I would then have to have an attribute on **Tag** that identifies whether it is read-only or read-write.

I'm wondering if there is a way to model this using multiple relationships between **Item** and **Tag** such that the two types of tags are kept separate from each, i.e. I would have an NSSet of userTags and an NSSet of factoryTags?

Thanks.

Comment: How about getting `UserTag` to be a child entity of `FactoryTag`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up multiple relationships between the same entities.  Control drag from Item to Tag and call that relationship factoryTags in Item and itemUsingAsFT in Tag.  Make this one to many.  Control drag from item to tag a second time and call this relationship userTags in Item and itemUsingAsUT inTag. Make this one to many as well. That way you keep the two separate using the same Tag entity.

Comment: Great, thanks!  I'd thought of two relationships but I was having trouble figuring out how I would make the inverse relationship from Tag back to Item point to the same thing. But yeah, it doesn't need to at all. Plus I am likely only to ever deal with the Item side of the relationship in my code, which now is logical with the two sets, and just like Core Data take care of the inverse side.